# Fetch data from database to input-group-addon

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

**Please take a look at the photos to view my problem**.

[image: (wanted)]

*On this photo, the list of services from the database are listed vertically.* This is what I want to happen

[image: (Current)]

While on this photo, *the list of services from the database are horizontally aligned*.

---

I want to display data from the database to bootstrap's `input-group-addon` Each textbox has a corresponding REQUEST button. The user can select what services he wants to request. But, I want to do it listed vertically rather than horizontally. Here is my code:

```
<h1  class="text-primary">Request Service</h1>

  <?php
   echo "<div class='input-group'>";

   class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
    function __construct($it) { 
    parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

    function current() {
    return "<span class='input-group-addon'>
    <input type='submit' aria-label='...' value='Request'>
        </span><input type='text' disabled class='form-control' aria-
            label='...' value='" . parent::current(). "'>";
    }

    function beginChildren() { 
    echo ""; 
     } 

    function endChildren() { 
    echo "" . "\n";
    } 
   } 

   $servername = "localhost";
   $username = "root";
   $password = "";
   $dbname = "crb";

   try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, 
    $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT SERVICE_NAME FROM services"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as 
      $k=>$v) { 
    echo $v;
    }
}
   catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
   }
   $conn = null;
   echo "  </div> ";
?>
```